# Is one third place enough, or ... I never met(a) site I didn't like

Tags: discussion, area-51

Even discounting the unicorns, waffles, and wassailing (*), meta is getting a lot of traffic. Retagging, lots of area51 issues.

Imagine that 5 or 10 of the proposed sites make it down the gauntlet and go live? Is it really practical to have one site as the meta hangout for all of them? Jeff's 'third place' [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/web-based-irc-for-the-trilogy) raised the topic of the use of meta as a place to talk about what the sites talk about. Could one site possibly accomodate all of that for all of these disparate topics? Or is the idea for meta to be narrowly focused on bug reports and questions about the mechanics of the platform, with some campfirish thing to be announced for community purposes?

(*) 'Carolling'

Answer (score 4):

I believe it was mentioned [on the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) that each site would have its own meta, and possibly chat room.

Comment: yes, each new site will have its own meta and chat site as documented here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/ -- that is the plan. This site is more like the government or state capital..