# Please add comments to the commitment phase

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase

Given the high bar on commitment, I submit that it would be very helpful to allow communications amongst the participants. They might coordinate drumming up more participants, or even in drumming up more rep for themselves on the trilogy.

However, the comment area on 'definition' stops taking new comments, and the commitment area has no comments. I think success would be more likely with a simple comment area to allow a bit of chatter.

Comment: Or have a proper meta question about it ;-)

Comment: Every +1 here helps those area51's I have committed to.

Comment: the trouble is, this might end up as a discussion board... but maybe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/web-based-irc-for-the-trilogy could help, too?

Comment: The commit discussion should be separate from the define discussion.

Comment: Currently I uncommit and recommit and put in a different comment.

Comment: @Tobias - What is wrong with a discussion board during commitment phase?

Comment: I desperately want to comment on the "Electronics and Robotics" proposal.

Comment: @Justin L - I think the concern is that depending on the direction of the discussions, a discussion board could re-define the site... even though the defining is supposed to be completed in the "definition" phase.

Comment: @Richard : Agreed. Nobody should be able to change the proposal once in commitment phase (otherwise you can subscribe to "robotics" and then the proposal becomes "Gardening"), however the initial proposer could decide to relinquish and close the proposal by linking to a different proposal to commit to. This would encourage coalescence of small communities toward a big one.

Comment: In addition of this, I think it should be the initial proposer to decide when the proposal is sufficiently well defined and the discussion is over, then promote it to commit phase. As far as I understand, now it happens automatically when the thresholds are reached.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes please.**

[Area51 GIS](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems) has over 500 commitments and is hanging there inches away from beta while [Home Improvement](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement) has leap frogged all the way, with only 200 commitments. 80% of the GIS people are committed to that and only that proposal, while 60% of Home Improvement will be splitting their attention among other proposals. This is frustrating.

Yes GIS will get there, and if a half dozen or so people continue to trickle in a day it won't be long either, perhaps a week probably not more than two. It's still frustrating. I want to **do** something to help, to build the site, not just sit here in the lobby cooling my heels. We can't even discuss the project with other people without going offsite, only there's nowhere to congregate (which is why a Stack GIS is appealing in the first place...)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes plz!!**

I've created An "Agile Software Development" proposal, but now I want to do some sort of merg with all the "Agile-related" ones but as this one http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7794 is in commit phase I can't even contact the one who created it to do so!!

Comment: good luck with pushing for an Agile Q&A - I really think the "Agile + Lean Q&A" has something going for it.

Comment: Thanks.. Actually that's why I'm pushing for the broader one (Agile) rather than the sub (just Lean, Scrum, or Kanban, etc).. But I can't find the means to contact the other guys :(

Comment: for now I added myself to the proposal committed members (I'm already into Scrum) put yet used it as a way to communicate my merge proposal by adding a comment about merging
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7794?phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is very needed. At the moment, there is no way for commit-phase proposals to host a discussion on how to get more committers, or to relinquish the proposal towards a larger community. Once a proposal reaches commit phase, we are all muzzled until the proposal opens and we get the meta, something that can take months, or even forever. This is rather frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

This is more or less planned -- we're actually planning to add general discussions to all phases of the proposal.

Now completed, details in blog entry:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/area-51-gets-organized-lets-talk/

Visit the Area 51 Discussion Zone:
https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is this part of the **current** implementation, i.e. Area51 discussion? Or are we waiting for something else?

Answer (score 2):

We might commit to the other proposal & add your discussion/question etc to the comments area (if you feel like committed).. it's not really a way for discussion, but at least it can start something..

I thought chat if introduced might help.. but then realized that probably it won't be permanent (& forum like) as a discussion