# Sending e-mail to people committed to a proposal

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Once a proposal is in commit phase, there's no way for the participants to communicate with each other (as far as I can tell). When the proposal goes beta, an e-mail gets sent out to the committers, so some list exists. My question is: is there any way to e-mail the committed participants prior to this?

Now, of course, this is a recipe for spam, and would have to be done very carefully. But my problem is that I'd like to get a sense of the community regarding a proposal that I'm heavily involved with — I didn't propose it, but I've been promoting it a bit — and currently there's no way of talking to other committers. I'd be happy to share my e-mail with the relevant moderators for approval so that they can verify that it isn't spam.

Comment: The factors involved have some overlap with [contacting another SO user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email is private. We can approve your intentions and all that, but in the end, members of this site did not ask to receive email from *you.* Providing private email addresses to a third party would be a serious breach of trust... regardless of their good intentions.

As a general matter of philosophy, we don't provide a routine means of users contacting each other. The Q&A nature of these sites focuses more on the *information* and less on the person-to-person connections of a social network.

If members wish to be contacted by other members, they will provide their email address in their profile.

Comment: that's I guess what I expected. The other question then is: is there a way to place an announcement of any kind on the landing page for the proposal, so that people visiting there could see it ?

Comment: You don't need to pass on actual email addresses - just add a way to send a message to all other committers, combined with an opt-in preference "allow emails from other committers" for each proposal.

Answer (score 1):

As I answered in a [question "similar but different"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55038/area-51-discussion-in-commit-phase) : having a meta website (even light) as soon as the proposition enters in the commit phase would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a link to `the third place` and have a chat room for people interested and /or committed. And I second the idea of an early meta page. I already receive a flood of emails from everywhere, and even if my addy is not given I have no way to prevent massive email traffic.