# Are committers actually sent emails when a site goes into beta

Tags: support, area-51, email, beta-phase

I see a reference to the fact this is happening in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56578/sending-email-to-people-committed-to-a-proposal), but I am committed to [this site](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) and did not get an email when it went into beta. I only knew it was in beta because Jeff tweeted about it and I happened to see the tweet.

Are other folks consistently getting these notifications?

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't receiving any emails because you haven't verified your email address. There is a link to re-send the email verification on [your Area 51 user page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/7610/cori).

Comment: Well that's pretty weird. I had done so on July 1, and when you posted this answer I re-sent the email (August 4th). Followed the instructions on both, but yet didn't receive an email when the English Language site [http://english.stackexchange.com/] went Beta.

Just opened the August 4th email again and hit the link and was rewarded with the +50 rep bump and notice.  Apparently those other times I followed the link either I really didn't or I did something else wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, usually something like this (I just got this last night for the Ubuntu site):

> Hey everyone!
>
> The Ubuntu Stack Exchange site, for
>   Ubuntu users and developers, is now in
>   private beta.
>
> Since you committed to the site, we’ve
>   granted you access at:
>
> http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com
>
> Please help us fill up the site with
>   awesome questions and answers so that
>   when we open to the public, the site
>   will be stocked and ready to go. The
>   questions on the home page when we
>   launch to the public will set the tone
>   and topic of the site for a long time,
>   so make them great!
>
> FAQ
>
> Q: Why am I getting this email? A:
>   Because you committed to support this
>   new site on Area 51.
>
> Q: Who can access the site during the
>   private beta? A: Only the 594 people
>   who committed to it.
>
> Q: How do I log in? A: Use the same
>   Open ID you use for other Stack
>   Exchange sites. You will be creating a
>   new account on
>   ubuntu.stackexchange.com, but it will
>   be automatically associated with your
>   account on other sites from the
>   network.
>
> Q: When will the private beta end? A:
>   The private beta will end and the site
>   will be opened to the public in
>   exactly one week, at 7 PM UTC on
>   Wednesday, August 4.
>
> Q: How can I help the site succeed? A:
>   During the private beta, ask
>   questions, answer questions, tag
>   questions, edit questions, and vote.
>
> Q: What else? A: The minute the public
>   beta opens on August 4, invite your
>   friends. Spread the word via Twitter,
>   blogs, and email far and wide. Hang
>   out on the site answering incoming
>   questions during the first few hours
>   so that newcomers understand what a
>   great experience a working, popular
>   Stack Exchange site can be.
>
> Remember – the private beta is now
>   open, but the public beta will open on
>   Wednesday, August 4: US Pacific - 12
>   PM US Eastern - 3 PM UTC - 7 PM London
>   - 8 PM Sydney - 5 AM Thursday
>
> Q: Where do we talk about the site? A:
>   We don’t want to talk about the site
>   on the site itself, so we set up
>   http://meta.ubuntu.stackexchange.com
>   as a place to talk about things like
>   what questions are appropriate, what
>   tags we should use, etc.
>
> Q: How long is the beta? A: The beta
>   will last at least 60 days. At the end
>   of 60 to 90 days, if the site has
>   enough ongoing traffic and enough
>   questions are getting answers, it will
>   graduate to a full-fledged, permanent
>   Stack Exchange. At that time the
>   community will decide on a permanent,
>   top-level URL, a web design and a
>   logo.
>
> Q: What else? A: Nothing! Go to it!
>   Here’s the URL again:
>
> http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com
>
> Yours,
>
> The Stack Exchange Team

Then you get another one when the site goes into public beta, but much shorter.

If you aren't receiving them, check your SPAM folder. If its still not there, try using / verifying another e-mail with Area 51. Services like Hotmail are notoriously paranoid when it comes to that, and its conceivable that several people who committed use the same mail service that you do.