# Should StackOverflow have a discussion module?

Tags: feature-request

My question is down to the fact that I have one closed topic, and one about to be closed.

Closed:
[Perls Of Wisdom For a .Net Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045624/perls-of-wisdom-for-a-net-programmer-closed)

About To Be:
[Is MVVM killing silverlight development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040829/is-mvvm-killing-silverlight-development)

Both are down to being "of a discussion nature" or not technically questions in the SO sense. I agree with that as they are not of the same ilk as standard programming questions. I have also noticed that SO has a large number of closed topics that are good discussion material and get some up votes before being closed.

Rather than spending time on closed topics that do not fit with the SO structure, it would be nice to see a place where this sort of discussion could be fostered. I feel both of my questions where interesting and so have others but I also understand the reason for people voting for closing.

Is this something that is being discussed or is this something members would prefer not to see?

Comment: *Is this something that is being discussed* -- Oh boy, if you only knew...

Comment: You mean `closed`, don't you? Locking is done only by diamond moderators, and only under extreme circumstances.

Comment: Yes, my apologies for that mistake!

@mmyers, I don't follow?

Comment: he means that you asked a rather naive question. :)  Search around for "subjective and argumentative" for just a small taste.

Comment: I see what you mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our engine is very poor at pure "there is no correct-ish answer" discussion.

We are planning a [third place for more real time discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/web-based-irc-for-the-trilogy).

Comment: Jeff, Thanks for the answer. I don't agree, I think the engine, with some minor tweaking is perfect. Its function in reducing noise is fantastic. Policy tends to be more the issue. My MVVM question, although discussed in an adult manner got "drive-by" closed with no thought for the participants. I don't know about real time discussion but if implemented correctly it could be great. Thanks for the response and link, Il keep an eye on its progress.

Comment: now that the chat is pretty much dead, isn't time to review this view?

Comment: @artb how is the chat dead? http://chat.stackoverflow.com looks very much alive to me. As of right now the top line stats say 48 users in 27 rooms, and it's late Friday night.

Comment: That is an average of 1.7 users per room... how many are actively in conversations? That's pretty dead. Java has _2_ users currently. If I want real-time response I'll find a real IRC channel. Also, the channels aren't bound to very specific topics or easy to search so they aren't good for the popular but closed as not constructive questions like this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/41045 . If I ever see Reddit or HackerNews link to SO I know the question will be closed as off-topic. Isn't that a problem?