# Why not have a discussions.#{sub_domain}.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should StackOverflow have a discussion module?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53781/should-stackoverflow-have-a-discussion-module)

I've seen a lot of good stackexchange content die on the vine because a question was closed as

"not a good fit for [the] Q&A format"

i.e.

[Scheme vs Common Lisp: Which characteristics made a difference in your project?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41045/scheme-vs-common-lisp-which-characteristics-made-a-difference-in-your-project)

Why not have a `discussions.programmers.stackexchange.com` where the question would be moved instead?

You would need gain a certain point level to be able to participate but at least the conversations and the good content along with them wouldn't have to just stop.

Comment: Because discussions don't work in the Q&A format.

Comment: There have been talks about having some kind of 'historical archive' separate from the main site for _old_ and _cherished_ questions that just no longer fit .. but the consensus is that anything like it would just detract from the value and focus of the main Q&A.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer: that is not the purpose of this site or the target audience.

There are plenty of forums on the web that are already perfect for this. There is also [Chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) (or other chats for their respective site)

The [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page explains it perfectly and even has this pretty picture:

[image]

Comment: That's basically what I was about to say. It would needlessly detract from our core Q&A. The reason we get it right is because that's all we do.