# How about adding an expert chat to Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, chat, experts

Sometimes when answering a question or getting a reply for the question leads to multiple questions. And then there will be some kind of follow up questions in the form of comments and it quickly grows to a big chain. Also people have to either watch the top message notification icon or refresh the page to figure out that there is a change in the question.

How about adding a chat functionality to the Stack Overflow? Once the chat is completed and the questioner can mark the question/chat as answered and the chat can be saved as answer for future reference.

Is there any such functionality planned or how can I propose this idea to Stack Overflow?

Comment: The original ancient post proposing a "web-based IRC" is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48249/web-based-irc-for-the-trilogy), for reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is "chat with an expert"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert). Sorry, couldn't help myself...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

:)

[image: Screenshot of the chat beta link]

Comment: In all fairness, the beta meta chat (funny story - that was my fraternity in college!) isn't really the same thing as an expert chat for SO.

Comment: @Jon True, but the actual question description didn't seem to have anything to do with an "expert" chat, it was exactly the use case for the current chat -- spinning off a live discussion for a given question

Comment: you actually *read* the questions? Man - I don't have that kind of time! :P

Answer (score 1):

See the little link at the top of the page where it says "chat.meta is now in public beta" -- coming soon for all sites.  <strike>You used to be able to create a room for a question simply by prepending "chat" to the URL.  That seems to be broken (at least for me) right now, though the FAQ for chat.meta.stackoverflow.com still indicates that's the way to do it.</strike>.  Prepend *chat* to the server name in the url for a question on meta (and navigate to it) to create a room to discuss a particular question.

For example:

[How about adding a Expert Chat to stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61360/how-about-adding-a-expert-chat-to-stackoverflow)

becomes

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/61360/how-about-adding-a-expert-chat-to-stackoverflow

Comment: If this was asked a year ago I think it would have been closed with malice by Jeff. But now we're really doing it. The world has gone crazy, I tell ya.

Comment: @Jon: now it's being *implemented* with malice by balpha...

Comment: The prepending thing seems to work fine: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/61360/how-about-adding-a-expert-chat-to-stackoverflow

Comment: @Michael - had to logout, then log back in.  Must have been an issue with my cookie.  I've seen this sort of thing before with the chat beta.