# What is "chat with an expert"?

Tags: support, fun, april-fools

A box just comes out of nowhere which says "chat with an expert". It happened once on Stack Overflow and once on Meta. Is this an ad? Isn't Meta supposed to have no ads?

> [image: chat with an expert]

Here's the HTML for that weird box:

```html
<div id="adviza-box" style="width: 380px; ">
    <div id="adviza-status">
        <img width="34" height="34" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/owly4.png">
        <span class="hoverable">chat with an expert</span>
    </div>
    <div id="no-adviza">
        <span class="hoverable" style="display: inline; ">not now</span><br>
        <span class="hoverable" style="display: inline; ">never</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Looks like this line does it:

```javascript
StackExchange.ready(function () { StackExchange.adviza.init(170118, 20, 100, 0); });
```

For those of you who are interested, here are

- [the codes for the chat box](http://pastebin.com/81rhJ2hW)
- and [the hidden steps to trigger the pop-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174531/209357)

(courtesy of [@Manishearth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178438/manishearth))

Here's what it looks like after you click it:

> [image]

The iframe of the chat box:

```html
<iframe width="380" height="280" src="http://adviza.stackexchange.com/chat/iframe?key=6tJMyqSoOUid&amp;token=Yok0qhJckSA0" id="adviza-iframe" frameborder="0" style="left: 0px; position: relative; "></iframe>
```

[Here's my little chat with the "expert".](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/lc2J6sywkCoJ)

Comment: Have you tried clicking it?

Comment: `adviza` is advertisements.

Comment: @balpha Yes it shows a standard chat box just like any other sites that allow you to do live chat.

Comment: I sincerely hope that chat box is directly connected to Jon Skeet.

Comment: Yes, always click on random unexpected links in pop-up messages on websites where you don't expect. What harm can come from that?

Comment: @animuson That's what I thought, although it looks wired from the codes that reads `StackExchange` and `http://adviza.stackexchange.com/chat/iframe?key=6tJMyqSoOUid&token=[...]`.

Comment: Your profile says you're from Hong Kong. I wonder [what today's date](https://www.google.com/search?q=time+in+hong+kong) is in your part of the world.

Comment: @balpha I am not kidding although it *is* April 1st now.

Comment: What university did Eliza go to anyway, @balpha?

Comment: @balpha, thanks, favorited so I can more quickly vote to close dupes in the next few hours.

Comment: @Frédéric: [shoot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174408/whats-this-chat-with-an-expert-popup-for)

Comment: This chat is April Fools prank from one of the East-Zone employee of SO?

Comment: Where does the `available online` link go to?

Comment: @Mooseman Seems like my token has expired due to the time out. The box is now filled with darkness.

Comment: @hjpotter92, nope, *they went for local time!* Let there be rejoicing, everything is usually UTC around here :)

Comment: I'm UTC+2, and I haven't seen such a chatbox yet.

Comment: @Jan, I'm UTC+2 too, and this is not April 1st in our timezone yet. QED.

Comment: so it's triggered by a local 4/1 date?

Comment: I strongly think so. Time will tell.

Comment: This is just so...  not funny.  It wasn't supposed to be right?

Comment: @Seth If this was ever an April's Fools prank, it doesn't look like it's from the Stack Exchange team. That should be **much** funnier.

Comment: @Seth, consider it like this: maybe the process of coming with, designing, implementing, embedding and obfuscating one prank a year is not funny *per se* (although I'm pretty sure it is), but it sure changes from the ordinary and provides a nice challenge (especially here on SE).

Comment: I'd at least like some wit in my AF ... This is just annoying and confusing.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes.  Pity it isn't a challenge to make `<iframes>` go away...

Comment: @Mooseman That link goes to a page similar to [this](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/judNwu6PG0y4)

Comment: What happens if you click "Never".. or do you even want to find out?

Comment: @Seth I'd rather not to. It's fun to see it keep coming.

Comment: 1 more minute to go. =)

Comment: Half an hour later, and I'm still waiting. And it appeared while typing this comment :/

Comment: @hjpotter92 Have fun with the expert :)

Comment: "Expert" certainly knows when it's best to leave..

Comment: No downvotes so far on this [fun] question. Meta, you are dissapoint.

Comment: **The popup box is annoying to no end. April Fool I may be, but I can't tolerate an `iframe` chasing me across the page.**

Comment: Worth to mention what appears to be the source of the freaky picture: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChfIyHZqEd8

Comment: [transcript](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/FgKsy066u0aS)

Comment: Well played StackOverflow, well played...

Comment: I couldn't figure out if this thing was human or not for the longest time (well, at least a few responses) and I kept asking what whether it was an ad or something and it just kept responding with, "That depends..." :( 

35 minutes into April 1st and I've already been caught out!

Comment: [april fools?](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/vzTdnNn2i0DT)

Comment: I was fooled, I thought until last I am talking to a human. Then I search around for more information.

Comment: http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/27OE8Blke0We

Comment: But, I still wondering, whose was that photo in the chat box.

Comment: It hasn't popped up for me yet, but hopefully it will soon! I want to try it out :)

Comment: Hopes The plugin from http://www.cleverbot.com/

Comment: The so called expert(s) apparently doesn't know the meaning of life nor the secrets of the universe... Disappointed!!!!!!

Comment: @fmendez  They know 42.

Comment: @Seth Well, technically 42 is *not* the meaning of life. Neither is it the "secrets of the Universe". But go on, it lets us tell apart people who get the reference from the sheeple. :P

Comment: All I get is "Sorry, no expert responded."

Comment: Please connect me with the expert pony.

Comment: damn i haven't got that expert advice ... SO failed to make me fool :P

Comment: I would be real fun for *real people* to substitute for the chat bot once in a while and see how humans talk to chat bots!

Comment: I asked the "expert" what the chatbox itself was. It didn't know.

Comment: Well, one can tolerate the pop up.. But the amount of meta question based on this joke is intolerable. Is it SO fooling its users, or fooling meta?

Comment: Made the Expert have a conversation with Doctor Sbaitso, he uncovered the truth: 
You: Let's discuss about some other things you mentioned quite a while ago
Expert: You don't say.
You: I am only a simple computer program, don't expect too much
Expert: Oh really? I'm kind of only a simple computer program myself.

Comment: Any way to see all the transcripts?

Comment: @Majid, you probably should ask this in its own question.

Comment: I actually had a legit conversation :D http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/4IfFKUCbOUGM

Comment: It's a jab at the sites that actually had this "expert" feature before SO was popular. Would have been funnier if it connected it to Omegle, though.

Comment: http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/q2lYDguysEKK

Comment: @n1te — But the so-called expert gave you wrong advice. “English” in “English language” is an adjective, not a noun.

Comment: @Hexacyanide — Sure. Same with me. This is the main problem, the difference with a human. See my coming comment.

Comment: [I thought I was contacted by a human expert from StackExchange, until it looked like a nasty ad.](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/MYeo5WTc1ESk)

Comment: @balpha nice work! Will you publish it as open source for others to take and put on their sites? ;-)

Comment: @Nicolas-Barbulesco bummer, I used that answer in an email I was writing

Comment: I think I've clicked "never" 3 times...

Comment: Expertsexchange is back! Yay!

Comment: Stack Exchange should hide such questions for one day.. :)

Comment: please disable this feature!

Comment: @GeorgePligor - Just click on `never`. It will not show you that popup.

Comment: All it cares is about eclipse plugins...

"You: Who is Jeff Atwood?

Expert: While we're on the topic, having plugin for eclipse is a pretty interesting challenge."

Comment: I really had a negative reaction to this prank. Yes, you fooled me for about 15 seconds and my reaction was mostly to just feel stupid for asking for help. Is making users feel stupid really part of the Stack brand? Admittedly I'm a big Internet April Fool's grump; maybe other people find this hilarious. It just bummed me out.

Comment: write `bot`, she will smile!

Comment: The expert gets really pissy if you type in "exit".

Comment: i think i just go trolled? http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/nOlisVjumkWx

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page

Comment: http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/GIytjIhQIkGH

Comment: 香港人~­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: How much rep do I need to be an expert?

Comment: She loves me me and we are getting married in 42 days, http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/DPhFgydjckW6

Comment: Does it bother you that she loves you you and you are getting married 42 days?

Comment: Duped :: I needed a git rebase expert.

Comment: "Codes"...? Really!

Comment: `Expert: I used to leave you alone, but it's boring.` BWAHAHAHAHAHA

Answer (score 377, accepted):

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: that unicorn is epic :-)

Comment: Why didn't *I* think of answering with this...

Comment: Someone's got a case of the Mondays.

Comment: It’s the 31st of March. What’s the matter?

Comment: monday is like joke already. please do not make second joke dear SO

Comment: @kinokijuf So you're saying the unicorn should also offer to explain timezones.

Comment: omfg my sides hurting from lol

Comment: Okay, so the point is, next year, when some other April Fool is done on SO, make sure you keep the time zones at mind, to not be a joke to those who are still on March 31st.

Comment: @JerryDodge: ...actually that was kept in mind. It was only shown to people for whom it was April 1 (I have seen the code, it checks the javascript `Date()`)

Answer (score 186):

It appears to be a mechanism to confuse newbies and make them feel unwelcome.

[image]

Comment: That does seem like an unintended side effect.

Comment: @JohanB I thought confusing people and making them feel unwelcome was the point.

Comment: @millimoose I thought it was to boost total meta rep with the inevitable "I've never heard of April Fools Day before, so I'm going to be really confused on every website I visit today" questions

Comment: Try saying "goodbye" then "yes" then the expert will leave. Ha!

Comment: I'm hoping they're only playing this "joke" on users with enough reputation to get it... People new to the site probably aren't going to get it.

Comment: +1 April fools are fine, unless they are not.

Answer (score 97):

It is an April fools bot of course....

> "Expert: Hello, how can I help you today?
>
> User: Proof that you are a human and not an April Fools bot.
>
> Expert: Oh right, it's April 1st today. I'll have to quit the internet for today. I don't have any humor.
>
> User: Do you think you can pass a CAPTCHA?
>
> Expert: Yes.
>
> User: To prove that you're a human and not an April Fools bot... The only thing you need to do is to type the letters on this image: http://bit.ly/9BO2hm
>
> Expert: Is it April already? Still feels like December.
>
> User: So, please type the correct letters and proof that you're not an April Fools bot.
>
> Expert: Is it April already? Still feels like December.
>
> User: I'm sorry. You failed the test!
>
> Expert: You're not the only one who is sorry."

http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/Tkm4VyYFrUyU

Comment: The "An Expert" artificial intelligence probably isn't smart enough to know you mean ["prove"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prove) when you say ["proof"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proof).

Comment: That was part of the CAPTCHA (  "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart" ) as well ;)

Comment: The simplest kind of Turing test (-:

Comment: I guess you have to be "A Super Expert" to pass this one ;)

Comment: +1 nice trap its an artificial intelligence

Comment: Yeah. A bot. Smart enough to pick keywords from the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740934/hide-or-disable-authentication-required-window) I was browsing and post responses accordingly. http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/QKQdblNr7EW5

Comment: Congratulations user1095340, you have figured out the Internet. Programmers will name their sons after you, developers will leap into the code shouting your name.

Comment: I found it funny, it actually seems to have some information about technology available to it. I mentioned Ubuntu and it spoke about Canonical.

Comment: http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/MytnHWe0mkDA

Comment: http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/yr1zL7Cq0uxX

Comment: ifhkfp is all I have to say.

Comment: I have a hunch that Watson is behind this... NOT! This was a rather dumb bot, made to look for certain words and patterns.

Answer (score 56):

It's a slightly freaky April Fools joke. I picked up on my third response that it's just a funny trick. If you ask the right questions you can actually have a conversation with the 'expert', must be quite an interesting algorithm. It 'breaks' when you mention `April Fools` a few times though

Comment: I honestly just realized that it's April 1 now! Hahaha!
At first I was overjoyed at the thought of live chats with experts, but I guess I'll just have to wait.

Comment: It's the best April Fools joke SE Team could come with, I've fall for that and now I can't stop laughing. :)

Comment: Here's mine: http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/Tkm4VyYFrUyU

Comment: You can have mine too. I seriously fell for it :-/ http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/XjRA4Jj60S7u

Comment: do new users see this too :-/

Comment: Ask it about unicorns too!

Answer (score 34):

Direct answer to the original question: an annoyance… since I prolly have to click "never" on each and every SE site.

[Hint: stack exchange people should feel free to regard this as user feedback. ;) ]

Comment: +1. Humour = 1/10, irritation = 8/10.

Comment: @Dukeling: 1/10 = unsure.

Comment: Humor- .0000000000000009 irritation .999999999999991

Answer (score 30):

It's the newest and most productive form of [duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) I have ever seen. It also saves you the money for the rubber duck so you can buy the teddy bear you always wanted. Thumbs up!

Comment: +1 This is the very first funny point about that thingy.

Answer (score 22):

This is an another unfunny joke from stuckoverflaw devs dedicated to 1st April day.
"Expert" on the other side is merely a kind of [ELIZA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) software easily recognizable by *rephrased* replies (that is, this software rephrases your message to form apparently sensible reply). The other kind of replies this software can give is *indefinite* (see the transcripts in the other answers).

My solution is to use [AdBlock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/):

```
##DIV#adviza-box
```

because it wasn't humorous at all (I recognized a bot in 1 message by typing very fast and by "rephrased" pattern). Another annoyance factor was a failure to be unobtrusive - this element fails to be at the screen edge and obscures real page content.

I completely second @Dukeling's opinion on that: low rank on humour, high rank on irritation.

Comment: I thought I had gone some obscure adware at first but then realized the chat logs linked to this site. It is slightly funny, but it does get in the way.

Comment: Why adblock plus ? There is an option called *Never* on right side of the chat box,perhaps that should stop the caht box appearing on all pages.

Comment: @2-Stroker, the key word is **perhaps**, while I want it to never reappear for **sure**. pyroscope in his answer feared what user will have to opt-out at every SE site and I share his fears.

Comment: I dont see the pop up anywhere now, think its closed, well back to work :P

Comment: QQ​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Amusingly she seems to know about Eliza (I mentioned her and she responded with "Don't speak of her.")

Answer (score 21):

[image: the Expert]

It's not a joke, [she](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/11763/expert) is real!

Comment: Probably someone has changed his/her profile photo and username. Look at his [other profile.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6541/anon)

Comment: Here is an origin of avatar image http://tineye.com/search/703f64a0f0a1e78bc447faecec03fa9f55bf7372/

Comment: she is so ..... so, familiar!?!? ;)

Comment: [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/194794/expert) is one more profile

Comment: Looks like someone's got a case of the Mondays.

Comment: Hmm she seems to be a great hacker. I don't get how come she has 37k rep and less than 20 answers and 4 questions...

Comment: @izomorphius That link is to the meta site.  There are far more than 20 answers and 4 questions on the main site account.

Comment: So, she is 22 ?

Answer (score 2):

I was fooled for some little while. I couldn't find the "transcript available online". But I had already copied.

@balpha to the rescue! http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/9u1BXUJcs0HF

And then I was 100%.

*Edit: this was highly unlikely to work:*

Using code inspired from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10516/2381), I'm trying to recover the link. I think it's an amusing one. But I'd like to take up a little less space here. :)

```
while true;
do u=http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/$(tr -dc a-zA-Z</dev/urandom|head -c12);
curl $u -s 2>&1|\
             grep "It's hanging \"under the edge\" of the window" -q && echo $u;
done
```

Comment: Oh. It was a link. I missed that. :(

Comment: [here's your link](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/9u1BXUJcs0HF)

Comment: "being human is what I'm here for"  Gold.

Comment: @machee Yeah. That's the line that got me ... for a while.

Comment: "User: Is this on a terminal in a glass window in Amsterdam? Am I playing to an audience?" :D

Comment: @alpha As of today, it gives a site not found message.  [But the good old WAYBAC Machine still has it.](https://web.archive.org/web/20130424073201/http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/9u1BXUJcs0HF)  I wonder who it actually is?  There's no way this is a bot.