# Let's get rid of all of the "Chat with an expert" questions

Tags: discussion, meta, clean-up, april-fools

Meta just got a *lot* of questions on "Who is the expert?", "Can I keep them", all the way to plain jokes like "The expert saved me millions of dollars". Besides our main question on the subject, ([What is "chat with an expert"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)) I think we need to delete all of the many, many, duplicates. Can a mod/10k/everyone else please help start deleting these?

Comment: Don't worry. I'm sure part of that will happen.

Comment: I resent the implication that my question was in any way the setup for a punchline. I really do want an answer, I'd like to recover the transcript of my closed chat.

Comment: It's a really, really, really bad joke.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: I ment the plethora of "Who is the expert" questions. There are a couple of legitimate ones, like yours.

Comment: Excluding the off-topic question and this question, there are currently only four non-"Who is the Expert?" questions currently on the Active tab :|  It was funny for about 30 seconds, but...

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers: Exactly. That's not good.

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers: It just came up for me on SO. It's a bit annoying, but, it did say "Truth" when I told it to "ask Jon Skeet". Hmm...

Comment: VTC as off topic, this should be on the meta meta site.

Comment: @Caleb, where can I post my request to delete this question after the questions this question requests to be deleted are deleted?

Comment: Is that you Mordac?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I don't think they have a fourth place yet. After [gold, silver and bronze](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) you just fall off the map.

Comment: Provide a good wiki-quality answer to the main question that covers the commonly asked about topics (what it is, how to get the transcript, how to get it back if you've dismissed it, etc) then start closing as duplicate... Then when you look for a question about the "expert" on MSO they all go to the same post which you should read, instead of having a lot of disjointed "Chat with an Expert" posts to read through to find *your* question. Nothing wrong with a bit of fun, but I'd like to try to contain it.

Comment: @Rachel: That should be an answer here.

Comment: @Caleb: this is the main meta.

Comment: @Linuxios: You missed the joke.

Comment: @Caleb: what was the joke? :)

Comment: @Caleb Sure, it's posted

Comment: Let's start with cleaning up this question `:)`

Comment: @CamilStaps: I guess your right.

Comment: Maybe Eliza will help.

Comment: It seems a bit disingenuous to me for TPTB to create the "adviser" as a joke and then get their collective shorts in a knot because it generates so much traffic.  Chill.

Comment: There's a certain irony that this question has two delete votes. I don't think I'll cast the third, but just wanted to point it out before it's deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Provide a good community-wiki answer to the [main question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174407/158605) that covers the commonly asked about topics related to the "Chat with an Expert" popup (what it is, how to get the transcript, how to get it back if you've dismissed it, etc) then start closing them all as duplicates.

That way users don't have to browse through a ton of disjointed "Chat with an Expert" posts to see if one exists that answers their question, as almost any "Chat with an Expert" post they click on will go to a single answer that will most likely contain the answer to their question.

This way we won't get repeats of the same (deleted) post, and no information will lost by deleting the duplicate posts. Also, we'd have one good wiki-styled answer we could keep it around for historical purposes.

Nothing wrong with a bit of fun, but I'd like to try to contain it.