# Does anyone read messages on review audits?

Tags: support, review-audits

Often, when reviewing a lot of edits I get a fake audit test.

I usually reject them with a message.

[image]

Are these messages stored anywhere, or am I just talking to myself again?

Comment: Did it ever occur to you to just click the *vandalism* option instead? :)

Comment: I guess it's like [chat with an expert](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174407/165773)...

Comment: They are stored for all time, waiting for the day that Homeland Security subpoenas SE looking for non-sentient salads.

Comment: They might come in useful when we get review audits for suggested edit review reviews.

Comment: I, for one, welcome our non-sentient salad overlords. I'm still trying to figure out how people *fail* the audits, since they're pretty obvious.

Comment: If you want answers from the void then you need to ask the right questions. In your example you have stated a fact that doesn't need any further comment :)