# When in many rooms, user's info goes off screen

Tags: bug, chat

So, I wanted to check what low-number rooms are still active so I joined a bunch of rooms in the chat.

This is the result:

[image: chat room]

Bug also exists when expending rooms on the side:

[image]

Since the position is fixed I can't scroll down.

#### Proposed fix:

Only show the first 10 rooms, and show `...` pointing to the user's profile for other rooms.

Comment: That's a good thing there are some mad users : nobody would have thought about this test unit :)

Comment: @dystroy [Always glad to be of service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180853/does-anyone-read-messages-on-review-audits) :)