# Admit it, adviza.stackexchange.com was a joke

Tags: bug, status-completed, april-fools

Over half a year later, people are still falling for the ["chat with an expert" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert) that was introduced on this year's April Fools' Day, through links to folks' conversations with our local expert:

[image]

As harald points out in their comment, [clicking the URL](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/WjS8p0MM9kGT) results in a [looooong delay](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LoadsAndLoadsOfLoading) that eventually culminates in an ASP.NET error with the only output being:

```
500
```

I suspect there'll be a bunch of these links still lying around catching people unawares while waiting to be flagged into oblivion. While they're still there and the [adviza.stackexchange.com](http://adviza.stackexchange.com) subdomain is still active, can we at least provide some useful feedback other than a stark 500 error page when someone visits one of these links?

I mean, *just admit outright that the whole thing wasn't real and you've just been having people on all along because you know I'm already on to you*. Or bring back the transcripts and continue messing with people.

Comment: I'm all for bringing the expert back.

Comment: This sounds like fun!

Comment: Alternative: redirect all requests to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174407/152859 :)

Comment: You have hurt experts' feelings, you insensitive clod!

Comment: Clearly, the answer to everything is 500. I'd say this is by design, since it takes a long time.

Comment: @Tim - you saying 500 is the new 42?

Comment: @Oded 11.9047% of the time, yes.

Comment: Just bring it back, but hook the functionality into the VLQ criteria of questions, so when someone asks something VLQ they get to get their answer from 'the expert' instead of bothering anyone else. Although that might be a bit unfair to the poor old expert though, but we can just wait and see if they complain.

Comment: @JonW Now I'm having flashbacks to actual support requests we got about the "expert". Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 27):

I admit nothing.

I've fixed the site for now, though.

Comment: Simply going to http://adviza.stackexchange.com/ leads to a 404 for me; it should instead show the general error message that this site "does not exist...yet".