# Unicoins: Is it really a good idea?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, unicoins

From what I have noticed from some meta questions is that users are seriously taking unicoins as genuine. My concern is that when they cannot access certain privileges such as talking in a chat room, they mistake it as a "bug" and then ask questions such as:

> Why can't I talk in chat rooms when I bought reputation using Unicoins?

I think we should at least tell them that it isn't real and that this only lasts for probably only 24hrs. It was fun and all until I realized how many people took it seriously and now these people have fallen prey and having been asking such questions, leading to major downvotes on their questions, damaging the likelihood of them returning to the site.

Is this really funny?

Comment: yes, yes it is.

Comment: If they mistake it as a bug, then surely they are bug abusing, no?

Comment: IMHO, seeing users taking it seriously is even more fun than the idea of unicoins.

Comment: You guys are Lol. But if I were them I would really not come back to the site after -6 downvotes on a unicoin question because they took it literal.

Comment: [You should ask an expert.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)

Comment: @n.1 it **IS** serious!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and you should definitely not check the date before creating such a post.
Maybe you should add a unicorn to your question so it draws more attention.

Comment: He did check the date, because mentioned that unicoins will only be available for 24 hours or so.

Comment: I think I will attract downvotes more or less.

Answer (score 19):

> Is this really funny?

No. Not even a little bit.

...but you can *make* it funny, for the low, low price of 110 unicoins! Just transfer them into my wallet, and humor will materialize... uh, magically.

<sub><sup>Limited time offer, void where prohibited.</sup></sub>

Comment: If you give *me* 110 unicoins, I'll pay you back in funnycoins! I promise, they're real! And valuable!

Answer (score 7):

*Is this really funny?*

Yes.

Creating a virtual currency based on unicorns is funny. But when people believe in it on April Fool's day, it's hilarious.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is essential for **any human being** in the globe to have both some `sence of humour` and some amount of `brains`
.

When people ask questions like `Why can't I talk in chat rooms when I bought reputation using Unicoins?` it means they probably have some troubles with `sense of humor` or ... well, you know.

The word **"Unicorn"** is already a *hint* that somethink is strange with it, you just need to remeber the simple fact today is the **1st of April**.

Just keep things easy, and don't even bother yourself and waste your time with silly things - and life would be wonderful. Have a good day!