# Well surelly unicorns and unicoins have made my day for today

Tags: discussion, community, unicoins, web

How long it will last though?

More detailed information needed.

Comment: Do you have a script I can use to mine some coins please. I need to close a whole lot of question, because they just are Unicorn!

Comment: No, buy he does have a script to make posts on Meta complaining about Unicoins.

Answer (score 5):

It will last forever! Unicorns for life!

Seriously, though, it will last 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Best answer around

Comment: @KeesSonnema Thanks! Yup, I'm probably abusing the word "seriously". And the word "forever", too.

Comment: Yes you are definitely.

Answer (score 2):

Unicorns will be around for ever.  Unicorns on Stack will probably become a myth on April 2.

I just wonder if all the posts on meta will also be deleted and I will loose all my lovely meta stack rep :)

Comment: [Posts about Adviza](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert) were not deleted so you will probably keep that juicy rep of yours.

Comment: @Omega yeah, 200 rep for many many users. This is a fine day to harvest Meta reputation!

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes I have run out of up votes trying to help others with there harvest :)