# This tag encompasses a large [web] of topics

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request, ambiguous-tags

We have a [web](/questions/tagged/web) tag here on MSE. I think it should go. It was 21 questions (as of now) with no tag wiki or info. It includes the following topics:

- The "web" version of SE (in contrast to the mobile app, which is now gone)
- [April fools and unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227589/well-surelly-unicorns-and-unicoins-have-made-my-day-for-today) (why is that tag even there?)
- Web crawlers
- The SE website
- The technologies/specs of various SE sites
- Design question about SE sites
- Random other topics

This tag is a mess, and I think it should go.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The tag is extremely ambiguous

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Maybe? Still a terrible tag.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Certainly no. See the bulleted list above.

---

Should this tag be burninated?

Answer (score 6):

I think your reasoning as to why a tag of [web](/questions/tagged/web) should be burninated are sound and that we should proceed to do that.