# Add a date range filter to the mass URL replacement tool

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, stack-exchange-team

Stack Exchange staff has a simple [search-and-replace tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232) to rewrite (broken) links without bumping the post. Can it be extended with a date range filter, so that it can update posts which were created, say, [before March 18th, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/295232)?

You might wonder what the benefit of that is. Well, right now there are about [a thousand broken links to user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F%22+created%3A..2014-03-18) here on Meta Stack Exchange. Posts like [What is "chat with an expert"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174407/295232) contain links to user profiles like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178438/manishearth which don't work; the correct link is https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178438/manishearth. For questions, there's some kind of redirect in place: just try https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1; it will automatically redirect you to this site.

There are some cases where users have the same user ID on (Meta) Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange, e.g. @annakata mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/295232), but I expect those cases are rare. (I could write a SEDE query to be sure.)

There might be other types of Meta Stack Overflow links here with the same problem, which could benefit from the same approach. I can of course direct my script to this task, but it will bump posts and take a long time to finish because I'll need to rate limit the number of edits it makes.